# How to solve 'lengths' argument should be a 1D CPU int64?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, stanford-nlp

I'm working on multi-text-classification LSTM model, but in the preprocessing of the text I'm getting an error that before I wasn't getting. I think it was an update on: `standfordnlp`.

---

**Code** were I'm getting the error:

**modules:**

```py
# StanfordNLP
!pip install stanfordnlp
import stanfordnlp
stanfordnlp.download('es', confirm_if_exists = True, version = 'latest')
stNLP = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma', lang='es', treebank = 'es_ancora', use_gpu=True)

# SpaCy
!spacy download es_core_news_sm # sm md
import spacy
spNLP = spacy.load('es_core_news_sm') #sm md
activated = spacy.prefer_gpu()
spacy.require_gpu()

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

**Getting rid of the stopwords:**

```py
def get_stop_words(): 
  # Getting in a list all the stopwords of the dataframe with is_stop() from SpaCy
  spacy_stop_words = list(dict.fromkeys([str(i) for i in spNLP(' '.join([elem for elem in new_df['descripcion']])) if i.is_stop == True]))

  stop_words = stopwords.words('spanish') # defining the language
  stop_words.extend(spec_stopwords) # extending the specific stopwords
  stop_words.extend(spacy_stop_words) # extending the spacy stopwords
  stop_words = set(stop_words)
  return stop_words

stop_words = get_stop_words() # defining the stop_words set in a variable to better understanding whe applying on the dataframe

# Applying stopwords on the dataframe
new_df['descripcion'] = new_df['descripcion'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in stop_words]))
```

**Lemmatizing:**

```py
def stanford_lemma(text):
  doc = stNLP(text)
  return ' '.join([word.lemma for sent in doc.sentences for word in sent.words])

# Lemmatization of dataframe
new_df['descripcion'] = new_df['descripcion'].apply(lambda x: stanford_lemma(x))

# Getting new stop_words after lemmatization
get_stop_words()

# applying new stop_words on the dataframe
new_df['descripcion'] = new_df['descripcion'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(
    [word for word in x.split() if word not in stop_words]))
```

---

**Traceback**:

```py
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-60972fc225b2> in <module>()
----> 1 new_df['descripcion'] = new_df['descripcion'].apply(lambda x: stanford_lemma(x))
      2 
      3 # Getting new stop_words after lemmatization (Lemmatizing: personalidades, personlidad = stopword)
      4 get_stop_words()
      5 

9 frames
pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/utils/rnn.py in pack_padded_sequence(input, lengths, batch_first, enforce_sorted)
    231 
    232     data, batch_sizes = \
--> 233         _VF._pack_padded_sequence(input, lengths, batch_first)
    234     return PackedSequence(data, batch_sizes, sorted_indices, None)
    235 

RuntimeError: 'lengths' argument should be a 1D CPU int64 tensor
```

---

*Update:* using the new library `Stanza`, I'm getting the same issue. An the issue will persist even if I try the *Lemma Example Usage*:

```py
!pip install stanza
import stanza

stanza.download('es', package='ancora', processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma', verbose=True)
stNLP = stanza.Pipeline(processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma',
                        lang='es',
                        use_gpu=True)

doc = nlp('Barack Obama nació en Hawaii.')
print(*[f'word: {word.text+" "}\tlemma: {word.lemma}' for sent in doc.sentences for word in sent.words], sep='\n')
```

---

*Requests:*
**Dataset (`@Crystina`)**: [new_df](https://github.com/GUNTERMAXIMUS/mbti/blob/master/mbti_new.csv)

---

*Any suggetion to improve the question, will be considered.*

---

Comment: heyy would you mind also share the `new_df `  you are using?

Comment: @Crystina yes, but I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with the `df`. Since they updated stanfordnlp to stanza the error start to happend. Also, the issue of the lemmatization is still happening when I use the `example usage` on their oficial webpage.

Comment: Report it on their GitHub page. But when you do, can you reduce the code here to a [mcve]? There's a lot here, and some of it may be irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: I will do it, thank you for the suggetion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only work if you use Stanza without loading spacy.
This is the error raised when you load `spacy.prefer_gpu()`
So don't load both the libraries in single GPU processing. Use them seperately.

Comment: Yes this is the answer, I think I give it in the stanza's github

Comment: Here is the full bug track: [Spacy.prefer_gpu() has conflict with Stanza use_gpu](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza/issues/337#event-3416999832)